# How to get second last key from JSON in Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to get the second last key from my json , I have tried

```
SELECT json_extract_scalar(json_column, '$[-1]') AS last_key
FROM table_name;
```

but it is giving the following error

awsathena error: INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON path: '$[-1]'

while using key name is giving me correct result, for result

```
SELECT json_extract_scalar(json_column, '$.status') AS last_key
FROM table_name;
```

is giving me correct output

Answer (score 0):

`json_extract_scalar` has limited json path support (and `$[-1]` does not look like a valid json path to access json property). Depended on Athena version you can workaround with cast to map (something along this lines):

```sql
SELECT element_at(m, cardinality(m)) last_key
FROM (SELECT map_values(cast(json_column as map(varchar, json))) AS m
    FROM table_name);
```

Also note that json is unordered in it's nature, so relying on the actual property order can be a questionable choice.

Comment: getting this error - awsathena error: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:25: Cannot cast varchar to map(varchar, json)

Comment: @VaibhavSka use `json_parse` on the column then.

Comment: can you please elaborate what you are trying to say

Comment: @VaibhavSka there is a Presto function called `json_parse` which turns column of `varchar` type into column of `json` type.

Comment: @VaibhavSka i.e. `json_column` -> `json_parse(json_column)` in my query.

Comment: is the below query correct ?

SELECT element_at(JSON, cardinality(JSON)) last_key
FROM
(select json_parse(metadata) as JSON
from sa_communication.communication_history  where template_id = 573 
and created_at >= '2023-01-30' 
and created_at < '2023-01-31' 
and status = 'FAILED')

Comment: Guru Stron thank you ,after json_column -> json_parse(json_column) is working, but it is giving me last key, I want second last, can you please help with that.

Comment: @VaibhavSka then use `cardinality(m) - 1` instead of `cardinality(m)`. Also possibly you will want to wrap `element_at(...)` into `try` if there is a chance there are json objects only with 1 key.